# Is there a way to change log level of a spark job at runtime?

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j

Using spark 2.1.1 structured streaming, is their a way to change log level of a spark job (using log4j) at runtime, without restarting the job.

Comment: Do you have a `monitorInterval` set (e.g. `<configuration monitorInterval="30">`) in your log4j config file? It is used to re-read the changes in the file, in general.

Comment: Spark 2.1.1 used log4j1.2, moreover even if I upgrade the log4j version, the log file is read from HDFS, so everytime the user will have to change the config file in HDFS. Basically I am looking for a direct approach without getting into this mess.